# Reading from a .txt file with multiple delimiter

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, logic, shortest-path

If you have something like this:

```
A-B(8),F(10),G(15)
B-A(8),D(20)
F-A(8),D(12),C(30)
```

in a .txt file
Format:

```
Store-NearbyStore1(distance),NearbyStore2(Distance)
```

How would you read and convert it to an array or something like an adjacent matrix?

Comment: Please, provide sample of expected output

Comment: `split('-')`, then it might be easiest to use a regular expression with `findall` to match the rest, because that can give you a nice translated list.

Comment: Something like this
{'A': {'B': 8, 'F': 10, 'G': 15}, 'B': {'A': 8, 'D': 20}, 'F': {'A': 8, 'D': 12, 'C': 30}}

Comment: Interesting that it's 2 miles longer from A to F than it is from F to A....

Answer (score 0):

There's no mystery here, you just have to do it.  Right?

```
text = """\
Monterey-SanJose(71.7),SantaBarbara(235),SantaCruz(43.6)
SantaBarbara-SantaMonica(92),Monterey(235)
PalmSprings-SanDiego(126),LosAngeles(107)"""

import re
from collections import defaultdict

mapping = defaultdict(dict)
for line in text.splitlines():
    a,b = line.strip().split('-')
    for dest,dist in re.findall('([^(]*)\(([0-9.]*)\)', b ):
        mapping[a][dest] = dist
print(mapping)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'Monterey': {'SanJose': '71.7', ',SantaBarbara': '235', ',SantaCruz': '43.6'}, 'SantaBarbara': {'SantaMonica': '92', ',Monterey': '235'}, 'PalmSprings': {'SanDiego': '126', ',LosAngeles': '107'}})
```

Comment: Would the answer be the same if the input from the .txt file is different like 
Monterey-SanJose(71.7),SantaBarbara(235),SantaCruz(43.6)
SantaBarbara-SantaMonica(92),Monterey(235)
PalmSprings-SanDiego(126),LosAngeles(107)

Comment: Did you try it?  (If not, why not?)  Won't make a difference.  I look for the dash, and then I look for the parentheses.

Comment: I did try using Monterey-SanJose(71.7),SantaBarbara(235),SantaCruz(43.6) 
SantaBarbara-SantaMonica(92),Monterey(235) 
PalmSprings-SanDiego(126),LosAngeles(107) 
but it seem to be reading incorrectly if there more than 2 nearby destination.

Comment: No, the problem is you did not specify there would be decimals.  My pattern matches digits only.  So I'll make a 4-character change in a moment.

Comment: Ah. Yes, I forgot about the decimals, and thanks for answering I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("path", "r") as f:
    output = dict()
    for line in f:
        name, content_str = line.split("-")
        inner_dict = dict()
        contents = content_str.split(",")
        for content in contents:
            inner_name, number = content.split("(")
            inner_dict[inner_name]=int(number[:-1])
        output[name]=inner_dict
```